# Translating media queries from LESS to SCSS

Tags: sass, less, vuejs2

I'm trying to update some old LESS style sheets into SCSS but am running into an issue translating media queries.

The LESS variables are as follows:

```
@lg: ~"(min-width: 1201px)";
@md: ~"(min-width: 993px)";
@sm: ~"(min-width: 769px)";
@xs: ~"(max-width: 768px)";
```

And are referenced in this manner:

```
.modal-dialog {
      margin: 100px auto;
      @media @md {
        width: 880px;
      }
    }
```

I've translated this into the following SCSS variables:

```
$lg: "#{min-width: 1201px}";
$md: "#{min-width: 993px}";
$sm: "#{min-width: 769px}";
$xs: "#{max-width: 768px}";
```

and the following usage:

```
.modal-dialog {
  margin: 100px auto;
  @media ($md) {
    width: 880px;
  }
}
```

The code in question belongs to a .Vue component and is being compiled using SASS Loader FWIW.  The code compiles (no errors) but the actual queries don't seem to be working.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the CSS files produced from SCSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SCSS / SASS the recommended approach to storing full media queries as variables is as follows:

```
$lg: "(min-width: 1201px)";

.modal-dialog {
    margin: 100px auto;

    @media #{$lg} {
        width: 880px;
    }
}
```

Which compiles to

```
.modal-dialog {
    margin: 100px auto;
}

@media (min-width: 1201px) {
    .modal-dialog {
        width: 880px;
    }
}
```